# Where to find the full text of "typing" options in gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

While trying to fiddle with my multi-language keyboard configuration broken by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322), I stumbled again on this screen in gnome-tweak-tool, "typing" section:

[image: gnome-tweak-tool -> typing -> caps lock]

As you can see, option text is severely truncated and there is no tooltip emerging to explain the full function (the same problem is repeated on most of the other drop-down menus). I say "again" because [I filed this bug some time ago](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool/+bug/1248736).

**The question**: is there somewhere a place (configuration file, gsetting, dbus comment, source file, whatever) where I can find the full text of the options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my 13.10 box I found them in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.{xml,lst}` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.{xml,lst}`. The XMLs are identical, as are the LSTs (at least in my case), so I think any one of them would have the full text you seek.

Another thing you can do is modify `gnome-tweak-tool` so you can see the entire text. Here's how I "fixed" mine:

`usr/share/pyshared/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_typing.py`, line 56 - makes the comboboxes in the Typing section display more characters:

```
#renderer.props.max_width_chars = 40
renderer.props.max_width_chars = 80
```

`/usr/share/pyshared/gtweak/tweakview.py`, line 49 - resizes the tool window so there is space for the comboboxes:

```
#self._main_window.set_size_request(740, 636)
self._main_window.set_size_request(1160, 680)
```

These values work OK for me, but there are even longer text options that still do not fit. A better fix would be to add tooltips or horizontal scrolling, but I don't want to pick up up on GTK and its Python bindings right now. Let's hope the devs will take notice of the bug you filed.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 15.04 this file may be located here:

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_xkb.py`

Setting `renderer.props.max_width_chars = 80` worked well.