# How can I remap the Caps Lock key to be Shift Lock?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, remapping

I would like Caps Lock to behave as if it were Shift Lock - so when you have Shift Lock on and press <kbd>1</kbd>, it gives <kbd>!</kbd>. I am using GNOME, but if I can use a package for another DE on GNOME, I'm happy to hear!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Gnome, you can change Caps Lock beavior in Gnome-Tweak-tool, then Typing:

[image]

Unfortunately, [due to a bug/misfeature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424856/where-to-find-the-full-text-of-typing-options-in-gnome-tweak-tool), the descriptions are hardly readable (they are truncated too short). You should match that with the full descriptions in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` --- this seems the one you want:

```
 caps:shiftlock       Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock (affects all keys)
```

Just select a couple of them until you get what you want.

Comment: On Pop_OS! I used `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` to install Tweaks, then Super key and type "Tweaks" to find it. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in KDE at least, this is easily configurable in the Keyboard system settings. Various options for mapping Caps Lock to Shift with locking are available:

[image]

Comment: Can I get this interface in GNOME?

Comment: @Tim I'm not familiar with GNOME. You didn't specify in your question for which desktop environment you would like an answer. Having a lot of useful options for the keyboard is one of the reasons for me to use KDE only.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer :) I'll try and get it working on gnome.