# How can I reformat this Flash drive to be ext4

Tags: usb-drive, format

How can I reformat a Flash drive to be `not partitioned` and `ext4`? The `Disks` utility does not work for me.

[image]
This drive has no partitions currently and I have no need for `Master Boot Record` and it is not > 2TB which is supported by GPT, so I selected `no partitioning`.

I am using the `More Actions` cog wheel from where I select `Format`.

[image]

Here is the error:
[image]

Selecting `no partitioning` is not the only way to get this error. Selecting `Master Boot Record` or `> 2TB GPT` results in the same error.

I am of course presuming that `More Actions > Format` is a necessary step before adding a partition. If it is not, then why not?

Edit:

Proceeding to try random things tolerating Ubuntu far more than I should, I tried to `create a new partition` with the `+` icon.

[image: Create a new partition]

Here's the error:

[image: Similar error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a longstanding (reported October, 2012), incredibly overlooked bug: see https://askubuntu.com/a/629043/16395. It will be fixed in the next release.

The solution is to use [`gparted`](http://gparted.org/), or format the device with command-line:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/device
```

(necessary `sudo` and device name omitted for obvious reasons).

Anyway, I **strongly advise against** using a whole, unpartitioned device. It will probably not automount or misbehave in a lot of cases. Create a partition table, one big partition, and format it --- you'll lose a couple of megabytes but you'll have a much more standard device.

To use `gparted` (short guide because [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive?rq=1) has a video --- I hate that...)

After started `gparted`, remember to **(1)** choose the right device (triple check, and then again) and **(2)** *unmount* it if mounted (you can say it's mounted because then option like partition, format, etc are dimmed):

[image: gparted1]

then create a partition table if needed:

[image: gparted2]

and create a big partition with Partition->New. Choose **(1)** a primary partion, the **(2)** right type, and if you add a label in **(3)** this will be the name of the device when automounted.

[image: gparted3]

...and then format it:

[image: gparted4]

Notice that `gparted` will not do all the operation instantly. It will create a list in the bottom window...:

[image: gparted5]

...and to really do it you have to choose Edit->Apply all.. :

[image: gparted6]

... you're done!

And a final note. If you format your filesystem as `ext4`, you have to change the ownership of its root directory after the formatting --- otherwise it will be owned by root.

For `vfat` and msdos-like filesystems this is not a problem, because the auto-mounter will force the ownership to you anyway. In the case of unix-like filesystem this will not happen. So after you mount your new device, you have to

```
 sudo chown $USER /media/$USER/newdevice/.
```

...and then be sure that you have the same UID on all the machines you use.

Comment: Ok. I was not aware of the distinction between `no partitioning` and "one big partition". I don't mind losing a small amount of space to be more standard. I will try `gparted` and one big partition.

Comment: I found `gparted` needs to be run by the root. Later the device is owned by root, so if your label is Flash and your name is jack you would `sudo chown -R jack:jack /media/jack/Flash`. Perhaps `chmod` might be better.

Comment: Checking my other Flash drives, they seem to be owned by me and not root. Root ownership seems to have been a result of how `gparted` was used so if permissions is an issue, `chown` might be better than a liberal application of `chmod`.

Comment: @H2ONaCl --- right you are. I've added a bit to the answer.

Comment: I think your chown command has an unnecessary dot at the end.