# Shift lock key in Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, input-devices, input-language

Belgian keyboards seem to have shift lock keys, as opposed to caps lock keys. [Under Gnome or KDE, it seems trivial to change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628981/how-can-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key-to-be-shift-lock), but not so under Unity.

The keyboard layout is set to Belgian, and I tried several other Belgian layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command line way to turn Caps Lock into ShiftLock on Unity is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:shiftlock']"
```

Comment: That's an interesting one. Does that work on the login screen too, or just the Unity session?

Comment: @rubdos: Only session. To do the same system wide, i.e. including the login screen, open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and set `XKBOPTIONS="caps:shiftlock"`