# Capslock works on letters but not on punctuation

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I've installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my wife's desktop, and yes, she's that kind of user which types capslock to ponctually type uppercase characters...

Here is the problem : I have a french keyboard (PS/2 Logitech with multimedia buttons). Lubuntu detected it as "french azerty (obsolete)".

- When I type <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>, it gives me `A`
- When I type <kbd>Capslock</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd>, it gives me `A`
- When I type <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd>, it gives me `.`
- **When I type <kbd>Capslock</kbd> then <kbd>;</kbd>, it gives me `;`**

I tried to change the keyboard to "french azerty (variant)" but no change on the punctuation. The quite good indicator is that the top-left key under escape type either `æ` or `²`.

Do other french users had the same problems ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't bother me, I think it can be change into *System parameter* -> *Keyboard*

Comment: I don't think the CAPS LOCK is supposed to work on non-letters.

Comment: Capslock has no effect on keys other than letters. It means there would be no effect of capslock on number keys., punctuation keys or numpad.

Comment: On (my) Windows Capslock works on non-letters... Given that my wife comes from Windows, this is quite a bad transition... I'll take a look at @damadam 's hint later.

Comment: @Goufalite not on my Windows 10 (US keyboard), and not on any other Windows system or keyboard I have used in the past 15 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remap the Caps Lock key to be Shift Lock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628981/how-can-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key-to-be-shift-lock)

Answer (score 5):

From [How can I remap the caps lock key to be shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628981/how-can-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key-to-be-shift-lock)

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Start `gnome-tweak-tool`:

   ```
   gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
3. Change the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behavior from **Deactivated** to **CAPS Lock activate the Shift Lock**

   [image: default tweak tool]
   [image: CAPS Lock is SHIFT Lock]

You can now type `1234` with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (but be careful, Shift + Mouse on an application icon open a new window).

---

**UPDATE** for 18.04:

2. Start `gnome-tweaks`

   ```
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Go to *Keyboard & mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* (refered as *Options supplémentaires d'agencement* on my screenshot) -> *CapsLock Behavior*

[image]

4. Change <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> from *Desactivated* to *Use CapsLock as Shift* (there are some different options, test and choose which one fits to your use)

Comment: Since this is Lubuntu, I don't think gnome-tweak-tool would be the appropriate tool here.

Comment: Works on Lubuntu, but you must type `gnome-tweaks` instead... Quite buggy (hangs and crashes) but furthermore doesn't solve my problem even after a reboot