# How to make caps-lock an additional ctrl?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard

How do I remap <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> to an additional <kbd>ctrl</kbd>?

I have tried to modify */etc/default/keyboard* and reboot:

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

After doing that, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> became <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From one of my previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052067/829702), there is a few change:

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Start `gnome-tweaks`

   ```
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Go to *Keyboard & mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* (refered as *Options supplémentaires d'agencement* on my screenshot) -> *CapsLock Behavior*
4. Change <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> from *Deleted* to *CapsLock is also Ctrl*

[image]

4. Change <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> from *Desativated* to *CapsLock is also Ctrl* (refered as *Verr. maj. est également Ctrl* on my screenshot)

[image]

This is the GUI way, using `gnome-tweak-tool`, I don't know if it fits your goal

Comment: Thanks, this helped me quickly sort it out.