# Swap roles of 'Super_R' and 'ISO_Level3_Shift' keys of Apple keyboard on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard

I'd like to know how I can swap the right command key (Super_R) with the right alt key (ISO_Level3_Shift) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'd be happy to know the bash command or the necessary lines a need to write in `xkb` . Maybe you also know a GUI solution allowing to remap keys?

So, the right ALT key yiels the followingin `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0xd7, subw 0x0, time 26406541, (573,569), root:(616,621),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And the right CMD key yiels:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0xd7, subw 0x0, time 26614133, (241,590), root:(284,642),
    state 0x0, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Install `x11-utils` and start `xev` in a terminal. Edit your question and add the output for the both keys.

Comment: @A.B. I've added the details and edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file `.Xmodmap`

```
nano /.Xmodmap
```

Add the new definitions

```
keycode 134 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift

clear mod4
keycode 108 = Super_R
add mod4 = Super_R
```

Reaload `xmodmap`

```
xmodmap /.Xmodmap
```

And check with `xev`

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x0, time 10943583, (116,83), root:(153,147),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x26b, subw 0x0, time 11023111, (106,110), root:(143,174),
    state 0x90, keycode 134 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: This solution with Xmodmap works. But as mentioned in the question below xmodmap has been obsoleted.

Answer (score 0):

Xmodmap will not work; [it has been obsoleted](https://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395).

In gnome, I think that you can do what you want with `gnome-tweak-tool` (I think there is an equivalent `unity-tweak-tool` or similar for Unity):

[image: g-t-t typing]

...should be one of those options. To [read the complete definition, due to a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424856/where-to-find-the-full-text-of-typing-options-in-gnome-tweak-tool), you need to dig into the files `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/*.lst` --- i think the one interesting to you would be

> altwin:ctrl_alt_win  Ctrl is mapped to Alt keys, Alt is mapped to Win keys

from `xorg.lst`, which I suppose is the fourth one in the list.

I cannot check it, but maybe

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win
```

can work... from [the usually useful arch page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension).

*(and yes, `xkb` or at least its current status is a PITA. Complex, undocumented system which I am sure noone knows in detail. See the first quote [here](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html). ).*

Comment: Unfortunately I the Unity Tweak Tool does not provide such a configuration. I'll try to dig in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/..." files then.

Comment: I don't really understand what to do with the files in that folder. I'd really like to avoid studying the whole xkb configuration? Does anyone have experience with it?

Comment: @ndrizza , I added a bit to the answer --- a simple guess. Unfortunately, it's a (over?)complex thing.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link! I'll study the documentation there.